# Google Maps click event not firing for addDomListener on mobile device but works on desktop browsers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, listener, google-maps-mobile

I have two buttons

```
<CENTER><button id="prevbutton" type="button">Prev &#171;</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="nextbutton" type="button">Next &#187;</button>
```

Defined above.

I want to change the directions when a button is clicked with the code below.

```
    function attachInstructionText(marker, text) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            stepDisplay.setContent(text);
            stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(16);
          });
        }
        calcRoute();
        var prevbutton=  document.getElementById("prevbutton");
        var nextbutton=  document.getElementById("nextbutton");
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(prevbutton, 'click', function() {
            if(stepnumber>0){
            stepnumber-=1;
            if(directionsvisiblemarker&&directionsvisiblemarker!=null){
                directionsvisiblemarker.setVisible(false);
            }
            directionsvisiblemarker=mArray[stepnumber];
            google.maps.event.trigger(directionsvisiblemarker, 'click');
        }

        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(nextbutton, 'click', function() {
            if(stepnumber<totalsteps){
                stepnumber+=1;
                if(directionsvisiblemarker&&directionsvisiblemarker!=null){
                    directionsvisiblemarker.setVisible(false);
                }
                directionsvisiblemarker=mArray[stepnumber];
                google.maps.event.trigger(directionsvisiblemarker, 'click');
                console.log(directionsvisiblemarker);
            }
        });

};
```

The above code works for at least the safari and chrome desktop browsers but doesnt work for mobile devices.
I also tried replacing click with mouseup but had no success.

Comment: It might be enlightening to do some mobile debugging with Adobe Shadow (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/).  Shadow's remote inspection feature has the option for remote JavaSript console...  Also, you should consider posting a JSFiddle